# use of same as in comparisons

Tags: grammar

is the following sentence correct: " the syllabus for the second semester is same as that of first one."
the difficulty is whether I must use "that of" in this sentence or not. Will the sentence be correct without "that of"?

Comment: You're definitely missing some "the"s - "The syllabus for the second semester is the same as (that of) the first."

Comment: Thanks. but my query was not about use of article

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&content=is+same+as%2Cis+the+same+as&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20same%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20same%20as%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, grammar aside, I think the intended meaning is totally obvious from each version.  This is not a case where you would draw the wrong meaning from one version but not the other.  So as a matter of communicating the key point, either version works effectively, and would likely occur in speech, and only grammar nuts would care.

Second, as a matter of ideal grammar and rules, I think both versions are wrong.  A correct version would use "for" not "of", thus (inserting the missing articles which you said are not your concern): "the syllabus for the second semester is the same as that *for* the first one".

Why doesn't "is the same as the first one" (i.e., dropping "that of") work?  Because "is" must refer to the syllabus, and "first one" must refer to the semester, and "same as" is like an equals sign: you would be saying the syllabus is the same as the semester, which it is not.

Why doesn't "is the same as that of the first one" work?  It's arguably correct, but not parallel structure - it says the syllabus *for* the first semester is the same as the syllabus *of* the second semester.  "for" seems like the better word in that phrase, and moreover, different constructions in the two halves of the sentence make the sentence slightly more confusing and harder to parse and understand.

So if you want to keep this structure and be grammatically most correct, I'd say "the syllabus for the second semester is the same as that for the first one".

Answer (score 0):

The syllabus for the second semester is same as that of first one.

I cannot see the difficulty in using *that of* but will take your word for it. The *that* refers to the syllabus and says it will be used in the second semester. Leaving just those word out entirely would be an odd and perhaps confusing sentence.

One alternative:"The syllabus for the second semester is same as *the* first." Here *the* references the semester, not the syllabus. The use of the word *one* at the end does not add a thing.